# Regular expression matching all characters including carriage return

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

What is the regular expression that matches all characters (`.*`) also with a carriage return?

Comment: You can use `'/.*/s'`

Comment: Here's a link for other modifiers you can use, http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Regular expression that matches all characters (.*) with also carriage return?

It is

```
(?s).*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dN1pI1/1)

The `(?s)` flag makes `.` match any character, even a newline.

The flag can be set after the second delimiter, too:

```
$re = "/.*/s";
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/dN1pI1/2)